# Samsung Social Hub: How can I view the sent folder running ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-touchwiz

I have 3 email accounts under Social Hub, how can I view sent folder running ICS 4.0.3  on Samsung Galaxy S2?

When I was using Gingerbeard 2.3.6, it was very simple to move the other mail folder as well. But now there is no such option.

Is there a way to see other mail folder like send items/ draft / myfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You can tap the 'Labels' button in Gmail's action bar. From there you can navigate to all labels you have in Gmail, including 'Sent' and 'Draft'.